# LDAP over SSL in Java - Exception: simple bind failed

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

Disclaimer: This post is similar to these - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066430/javax-naming-communicationexception-simple-bind-failed), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389689/ldap-over-ssl-with-java). **HOWEVER, it is not the exactly the same. The stack trace is different. I followed the answers in those posts and they do not help solve my issue, or else I don't understand them completely. Since I cannot comment on these posts, I ask my question here.**

OK, so we want to enable LDAP over SSL (aka LDAPS) support for one of our products that is currently working with standard LDAP. I haven't been able to get it to work so if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, please advise.

I followed the procedure [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Configuring+an+SSL+Certificate+for+Microsoft+Active+Directory) to issue and install the SSL certificate. That procedure includes the installation of the certificate on the Java key store, as specified by [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066430/javax-naming-communicationexception-simple-bind-failed). This the command I used to install the certificate:

```
keytool -import -keystore .\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file path\to\client.crt
```

Note that the key store specified is 'cacerts', perhaps this is wrong (?).

The code I used to initialize the context:

```
...
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://" + serverAddress);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, administratorName);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
LdapContext ldapContext = null;
try {
    ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
...
```

Here I get an exception - "simple bind failed..", with the following stack trace:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: 172.23.30.104:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

The program works (without SSL obviously) by dropping the SECURITY_PROTOCOL line, and changing the provider url to "ldap://..." (without the 's').

So again, what is missing here?

Cheers,
Gilad.

Comment: I know it's duplicate but I can't comment on the older ones, and they do not solve my issue.

Comment: Two things - try to import the CA certificate into your keystore using `keytool -import -keystore .\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file path\to\ca.crt -trustcacerts` and if that does not help, try to use your own keystore using `Security.addProvider( new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider() );` and `System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.trustStore", <your-ldap-keystore> );`